# How to set individual "Was this helpful?" surveys on FAQs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 36 FAQs, and answers on one page. Each answer is contained inside a collapsible element. My goal is to have the user click yes or no, in the FAQ and I track that value through GTM/GA. However, when I currently click yes or no, that value is displaying the "Thanks for your feedback." alert to all the FAQs.

I know this has to do with the way I'm utilizing my elements by class vs id, but I'm not entirely sure what to do.

My snippet below shows the current state.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".survey-submit").click(function() {
        $(".survey-alert").show();
        $(".survey").hide();
      });
    });
```

```css
.survey-alert {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</p>
          <div class="row float-right text-center">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="survey">
                      <h6>Was this helpful?</h6>
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary text-white mr-3 survey-submit">Yes</button>
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary text-white survey-submit">No</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable survey-alert">
                      Thanks for your feedback.
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</p>
          <div class="row float-right text-center">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="survey">
                      <h6>Was this helpful?</h6>
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary text-white mr-3 survey-submit">Yes</button>
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary text-white survey-submit">No</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable survey-alert">
                      Thanks for your feedback.
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>         
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</p>
          <div class="row float-right text-center">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="survey">
                      <h6>Was this helpful?</h6>
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary text-white mr-3 survey-submit">Yes</button>
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary text-white survey-submit">No</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable survey-alert">
                      Thanks for your feedback.
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>         
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're selecting the elements to hide/show by their class name as you could figure, doing so will apply the effects on all the elements with the selected class name, in order to solve that you can use the following approach:

1. selecting the current clicked button's 1st parent (the div with class name "survey") and hiding it using:
   `$(this).parent().hide()`this can be done because the element that
   you want to hide is the 1st parent of the clicked button.
2. Selecting the 2nd parent of the clicked button,then selecting its
   child element with "survey-alert" class name and show it using: 
   `$(this).parents(':eq(1)').find(".survey-alert").show();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".survey-submit").click(function() {
       $(this).parents(':eq(1)').find( ".survey-alert" ).show();
        $(this).parent().hide();
      });
    });
```

```css
.survey-alert {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</p>
          <div class="row float-right text-center">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="survey">
                      <h6>Was this helpful?</h6>
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary text-white mr-3 survey-submit">Yes</button>
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary text-white survey-submit">No</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable survey-alert">
                      Thanks for your feedback.
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</p>
          <div class="row float-right text-center">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="survey">
                      <h6>Was this helpful?</h6>
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary text-white mr-3 survey-submit">Yes</button>
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary text-white survey-submit">No</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable survey-alert">
                      Thanks for your feedback.
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>         
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</p>
          <div class="row float-right text-center">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="survey">
                      <h6>Was this helpful?</h6>
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary text-white mr-3 survey-submit">Yes</button>
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary text-white survey-submit">No</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable survey-alert">
                      Thanks for your feedback.
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>         
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can find in the following links the documentation of the used methods:

parents(): https://api.jquery.com/parents/

parent(): https://api.jquery.com/parent/

find(): https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Great approach. Thanks Mahfoudh!

Comment: An explanation of what was wrong with the OP original code, why, and how your fix solved the problem would make this a _much_ better answer. A code dump with no explanation solves the immediate problem, but doesn't do much to help anyone learn. @webfrogs basic problem is with `$(".survey-alert").show();` because it selects _every_ element with class survey-alert all at once, then shows all of them.

Comment: Good point, @StephenP. Mahfoudh - Can you provide some insight into this?

Comment: @StephenP  ,Webfrogs,   Thank you for your feedback, i have edited my post with more details about the problem and its solution.